# css transitions "triggers" on browser resize

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I can't figure out how to avoid css transitions to execute, when you go from mobile first to desktop via media query.

I would like to have and transition on hover, but also when you hover out on a svg logo etc. I have a smaller logo for mobile, and larger for desktop. But the transition effects the new width and triggers a hover transition aswell.

Any idea how you can void transitions to "execute" when new style via a media query gets applied.

I have made an example with my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/yw2L2u7s/

```
<div class="logo"></div>

.logo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 525px) {
    .logo {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background: blue;
    }

    .logo:hover {
        background: yellow;
    }

    .logo {
        -webkit-transition: ease 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: ease 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: ease 0.5s;
        -o-transition: ease 0.5s;
        transition: ease 0.5s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I see what the problem is here, it will only be seen by people who decide to resize their browser to a mobile size and not actual users of mobile/tablet devices

Comment: You haven't said what you want to transition so it's transitioning everything. If you want to transition one thing...tell it to only transition that property.

Comment: I have taken a mobile first approach. I didn't want hover effects for mobile and tablet, but @1024px in my project it changes to desktop style, and I have applied hover effects on logo, menu links etc. But... it triggers the hover when you resize to from lets say 500px to 1024px. 

Live example: http://instagib.dk/

Comment: Frankly, the way CSS transitions are designed it's difficult to come up with a pure CSS solution for this. Your best bet is to just assume not every one of your desktop visitors is going to be resizing their browser just to see if this sort of thing happens. Quite a cop-out, I know, but unless you're willing to use JS, there's not much of a CSS workaround.

Comment: Hey Bolt, yea it seems I only can apply a transition on the :hover selector. I think the users will survive. Or I can add the effects in the mobile first css file... Is there any good way to turn off hover states on IOS?

Comment: BoltClock, is there a solution for this? Javascript etc? I've seen sites like basicagency do it. Their effects don't trigger, yet they have fadeIn and fadeOut effect on their hovers. :/

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and finally I solved it with some javascript code.

**Code explanation:** When the window is resized, it adds the `stop-transition` class to the `body` element. After short timeout it removes this class.

```
stopResponsiveTransition();

function stopResponsiveTransition() {
  const classes = document.body.classList;
  let timer = null;
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    if (timer){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = null;
    }else {
      classes.add('stop-transition');
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      classes.remove('stop-transition');
      timer = null;
    }, 100);
  });
}
```

Also add this rule to your CSS sheet. It resets the transition property for the chosen element during the resize. After the resize event (short timeout) this class is removed so the rule below is not respected and the transition works again for all user actions on this element.

```
body.stop-transition #some-grid-container{
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution, worked a treat. Some people question why this is even necessary but its these tiny differences that make all the difference

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and finally found a fix.

This one should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.onresize = resizePage; 
   resizePage();
});
function resizePage(){
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if(width >= 525 && width <= 526){ // your page breakpoint happens probably between 525px and 526px width at this range we gonna disable the transition temporarily
        $(".logo").css( "transition-property", "none" ); // temporarily disable the transition on .logo
    } 
    else{
        $(".logo").css( "transition-property", "" ) // else restore the actual transition
    }
}
```

**Note:** if you want to temporarily disable all transitions at the breakpoint range, you can use the `*` selector, which selects all elements.

```
$("*").css( "transition-property", "none" );
```

Answer (score 1):

since you just modify the background color, just specify the property to transition so it will be the only property affected :

```
.logo {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 525px) {
    .logo {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .logo:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .logo {
        -webkit-transition: background-color ease 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: background-color ease 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: background-color ease 0.5s;
        -o-transition: background-color ease 0.5s;
        transition: background-color ease 0.5s;
    }
}
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jox15urm/

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to disable the transition for a second when the window is resized then renable it (worked for me):

html :

```
 <body onresize="ChangeTransition()>
 <div class="logo" id="logo">
```

javascript :

```
function ChangeTransition(){
document.getElementById("logo").style.transition = "none";
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("logo").style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You guys are genious, Thanks! I adapted this for jQuery.

$(window).resize(function() {
document.getElementById("logo").style.transition = "none";
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("logo").style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
}, 100);
});